# phonegap permission for bluetooth without bluetooth

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, phonegap, diagnostics

### Phonegap

**config.xml**

```
...
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
...
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
...
<preference name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic.modules" value="CAMERA" />
....
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic"/>
```

My app does not work with bluetooth however when installing it requires permission to link with bluetooth devices

**phonegap log**

```
...
...
Fetching plugin "cordova.plugins.diagnostic" via npm
Installing "cordova.plugins.diagnostic" at "4.0.8" for android
...
...
```

If I erase <preference name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic.modules" value="CAMERA" /> everything remains the same

Answer (score 2):

The Diagnostic plugin uses an [npm postinstall hook](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/blob/master/package.json#L43) to run a [hook script](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/blob/master/scripts/apply-modules.js) which applies the preference in `config.xml` to comment out unwanted modules.

Therefore [as documented](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#specifying-modules):

> It's vital that the preference be added to your config.xml before you install the plugin, otherwise the preference will not be applied and all modules will be added. This is because, due to limitations of the Cordova CLI hooks, this plugin must use the npm install process to apply the module preferences and this runs before the Cordova CLI when installing a plugin. If you change the modules specified in the preference, you'll need to uninstall then re-install the plugin to your project to apply the changes.

So you should try:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova.plugins.diagnostic --nosave
npm uninstall cordova.plugins.diagnostic
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic --nosave
```

Note: if you use symlinks with your project or `node_modules`, this can cause the script to fail because it cannot resolve the correct relative paths.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the Cordova Diagnostic plugin.

Comment: I work with phonegap...<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" /> ... I dont install or re-install the plugins... they are installed every time: the preference be added to your config.xml before you install the plugin.

Comment: Anyway, I have the same problem if I do not use the modules <preference name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic.modules" value="CAMERA" />

Comment: @DaveAlden what is the solution for v3.7.1?  We put out a fix on an old application that is being replaced, but hasn't been deployed in over a year, and we get this error now.  Unlike v4 we can't preferentially remove bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

The **[cordova.plugins.diagnostic](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#bluetooth-module)** plugin **does** use the Bluetooth functionality, as you can see from the Readme.

If you are including a plugin with the description

> Cordova/Phonegap plugin to manage device settings

it will surely ask for all possible permissions. Why would you need such plugin, anyway?

Comment: You can see [modules] (https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#specifying-modules) The plugin does not use the Bluetooth funcionality and it does not ask me for others perssissions like microphone, contacts,...I do not use either

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to disable adding permission in AndroidManifest.xml by removing few lines of code from **android.json**

Remove:

```
      {
          "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.BLUETOOTH\" />",
          "count": 1
        }
```

If it is still adding BLUETOOTH Permission delete all the lines which had "bluetooth" in it.